# Resolution Problem with HttpRequestScoped in Autofac

Tags: asp.net, ioc-container, autofac

I'm trying to resolve the AccountController in my application, but it seems that I have a lifetime scoping issue.

```
builder.Register(c => new MyDataContext(connectionString)).As<IDatabase>().HttpRequestScoped();
builder.Register(c => new UnitOfWork(c.Resolve<IDatabase>())).As<IUnitOfWork>().HttpRequestScoped();
builder.Register(c => new AccountService(c.Resolve<IDatabase>())).As<IAccountService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => new AccountController(c.Resolve<IAccountService>())).InstancePerDependency();
```

I need MyDataContext and UnitOfWork to be scoped at the HttpRequestLevel.
When I try to resolve the AccountController, I get the following error:

No scope matching the expression 'value(Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3+<>c__DisplayClass0[...]).lifetimeScopeTag.Equals(scope.Tag)' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.

Do I have my dependency lifetimes set up incorrectly?

Comment: From which scope are you resolving the AccountController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup looks fine - I'd guess that the problem is that you're trying to resolve AccountController (manually?) from IContainerProvider.ApplicationContainer.

You need to resolve dependencies in a web app from IContainerProvider.RequestLifetime (RequestContainer in 1.x).

Have you tried the Autofac ASP.NET MVC integration? It would take care of this for you.

Comment: I still haven't solved my problem, but this was part of it.  I'm starting a new question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I solved it moving the registration instructions to the  Application_BeginRequest section in global.asax.cs

```
builder.Register(c => new MyDataContext(connectionString)).As<IDatabase>().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => new UnitOfWork(c.Resolve<IDatabase>())).As<IUnitOfWork>().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => new AccountService(c.Resolve<IDatabase>())).As<IAccountService>();
builder.Register(c => new AccountController(c.Resolve<IAccountService>())));
```

Then I have the disposal of the container:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    ContainerProvider.EndRequestLifetime();
}
```